# Initialization parameters for an Oracle PDB

Tags: oracle, oracle18c, oracle19c

How to query all Initialization parameters for an Oracle PDB without doing an 'alter session to PDB'?
Any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `con_id` column in `v$system_parameter`  view

```
  SQL>SELECT name,
           value
    FROM v$system_parameter
    WHERE con_id=
        (SELECT con_id
         FROM v$pdbs
         WHERE name='TESTPDB');
    
    NAME                                               VALUE
    -------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------
    cpu_min_count                                      12
    sga_min_size                                       0
    shared_pool_size                                   0
    resource_manager_plan                              SCHEDULER[0x4D18]:DEFAULT_MAIN
                                                       TENANCE_PLAN
    
    db_performance_profile
    sga_target                                         0
    db_cache_size                                      0
    undo_tablespace                                    UNDOTBS1
    tde_configuration
    private_temp_table_prefix                          ORA$PTT_
    unified_audit_systemlog                            FALSE
    parallel_servers_target                            192
    common_user_prefix
    multishard_query_data_consistency                  strong

multishard_query_partial_results                   not allowed
```